# How do I solve the expression $-(x-1)^3=0$ over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve: $-(x-1)^3 = 0$ over $\mathbb{R}$

If we substitute for $x$ using $1$ we yield zero. However, I need up to three solutions for $x$.

Comment: There are three roots but they are all the same ($x=1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x-1)(x-1)(x-1)=0$$
so there are three roots 
$$x_1=1$$
$$x_2=1$$
$$x_3=1$$

Comment: And the other factor, $-1$, is not zero.

Comment: These are not three roots, but one!! What we get is that the multiplicity of the root is $3$/

Answer (score 3):

I suggest reading a bit about [multiple roots](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultipleRoot.html). In your case, $1$ is a triple root.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind it says "up to" 3 roots. Therefore, there are three roots, but they are not distinct. The roots are x1=1, x2=1, x3=1.